# Web application for managing elections campaign

Tags: database, web-applications

I’m trying to help a friend in his election campaign.
We mainly need a tool to manage a list of possible voters. We need to be able to:
1. Easily update details about the voters, and
2. Query for voters according to various parameters, and show and print the resulting lists

To enable campaigners to work from multiple workstations, we would like the system to be distributed, probably web based.

We would also like that to be in Hebrew, if possible.

Is there any existing tool that easily enables it?
If not, can you recommend on an easy way to implement such a tool?

(I have a solid programming knowledge, but not much time to devote to that)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily with [iFreeTools Creator](http://creator.ifreetools.com). Just create the entities and attributes for Voters and add campaigners as users providing their Google email-id.

Regarding your requirements..
* This app is web-based. It runs on Google App Engine.
* The interface is English only, but data can be in unicode. Entity name and attribute names are also "data", so they can be in unicode too.

Other related features which might be useful in this context..
* You can import voter list using CSV files.
* Campaigners can search for voters near their workstation by filtering out records based on nearness to a geo-location.

// Disclosure : I wrote code for this web-app. Hope you like it. Feedback welcome.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like what I was looking for. I'll try to give it a try, but I think it might e too late now...

Comment: One problem I noted is that some buttons, like the "Add Random" and "Delete" buttons in the Entity window takes the user to an empty screen.

Comment: Sorry that I am late.. had signed up at StackOverFlow recently and was checking out the questions when I found yours. May be, you can remember about iFreeTools when you might require such online database apps at a later date. Will check for (and fix) issues in the scenario you had mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible answers might be found in [the same question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/web-application-for-managing-elections-campaign) I asked in the web apps forum